# Sharing badges for Community Wiki posts

Tags: support, badges, community-wiki, sharing

Does sharing a link to a **community wiki** post count towards the `Announcer`, `Booster`, and `Publicist` badges as well?

Given that you can't gain or lose rep when acting on community posts, I was wondering if this applied to the badges as well.

Comment: But you do earn post badges for CW posts. I don't think it CW affects badges in general...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, sharing a link to a community wiki post counts towards those badges.  For example, I got all three promotion badges from the CW post [What is the coolest thing you can do in <10 lines of simple code? Help me inspire beginners!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/811074/1288)

You can earn any badge by the normal rules on CW posts.